# Shift-invariant Sets Are Terminal Sets

Tags: probability-theory

**Quick version**: Shift invariant set is a set of sequences where I can add an element to the beginning of the sequence and shift the remaining elements to the right and the sequence remains within the set.

Terminal sets are those where I can change finitely many elements in the sequence and still remain within the set.

Collection of shift invariant sets $\subset$ collection of terminal sets.

Why, intuitively?

**Properly defined question**:

I am not sure how universal these definitions are (it seems more like they actually are very local to my lecture), so here are briefly the definitions:

> **Shift** $s:\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}\to \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$
>   $$s(x_1,x_2,\dots)=(x_2,x_3,\dots)$$
>
> **Terminal set**: A set $T$ is terminal if the following implication holds
>   $$x\in T, y\in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}, y_k = x_k\;\; \forall k\in \mathbb N \text{ except for finitely many} \Rightarrow y\in T$$
>
> **Shift-invariant sets**: $\mathcal I = \{I \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}): s^{-1} I = I\}$
>
> **Terminal sets**: $\mathcal T = \{T\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}), T\text{ terminal} \}$

where $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^{\mathbb N})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$

Now, the following inclusion holds
$$\mathcal I \subset \mathcal T$$

This is quite easy to prove if one realizes that

> **Lemma**: $T\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^{\mathbb N})$ is terminal $\iff \exists T_n \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}): T= \mathbb R^n \times T_n$

But such proof gives me no insight as to why exactly this happens. Both operations (shifting x changing finitely many elements) seem qualitatively different and it is surprising they have such relationship. Therefore I am looking for an insight, or perhaps even a full proof using the sets' definitions, as long as they provide an intuitive explanation as to why this is true.

Proof of the lemma as well as the proof of the inclusion with help of the lemma can be added if requested/needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not quite grasp, if the following is what you are after, but: Suppose $I $ is shift invariant and $x\in I $. As $I $ is invariant, $s^kx\in I $. So now we have "shifted" $k $ xs away. As $I $ is also closed under inverse images under $s $, every element which has the same tail as $x $, e. g. $y=(y_1, \ldots, y_k, s^kx) $ is an element of $I $. By definition, $I $ is terminal.

Comment: How do we know that $s^k x \in I$? It's not readily available from the definition of a shift-invariant set.

Comment: It is. As $x \in I = s^{-1}(I)$ implies $sx \in I$ by definition of the inverse image.

Comment: Oh my god, it is true! This semi-blows my mind. At the same time I really dislike the fact that I would never realize it wouldn't being (repeatedly) told it is so.